# Why is the page content always rendered after blocks displayed on the same page?

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

I have a Static Page node at, say, `/my-page`. It has a title and body. I have also placed a block (pointing to a View) in the "Main content" region, at the very bottom of the list.

However, when viewing /my-page, the block is displayed above the `<article>` element that contains the page content. An example can be seen below.

[image: Article element rendered at the very bottom of the region]

Why is this the case? What can I do to always show the page content *above* everything else that is placed in the same region?

Comment: `monty` is the name of the theme, and the overridden `block.html.twig` and `node.html.twig` files do not change the order of anything.

Comment: Did you inspect the weights of the blocks on the block admin page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to adjust the display order of the blocks through configuration. Navigate to `Manage >> Structure >> Block layout` (relative path: `/admin/structure/block`), click the handle icon next to the "Main page content" block and use it to drag the block to the top of the "Content" region.

Comment: It's so weird that the main page content *still renders* regardless of whether this block is placed, so I missed it entirely. I had no idea such a block existed.

Comment: Yes, there's a fallback system in place because your side would basically be dead if that would no longer display